# Socket.io, difference between socket.set() and socket property?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

Socket.io recommends settings per-socket variables like so:

`socket.set('foo', bar, function () {});`

Variables can also be set and accessed on the socket:

`socket.foo = bar`

Is there a benefit to using the provided set() function?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Calling `socket.foo` sets your property on the socket object itself. This isn't recommended because you could be overriding an internal property that socket uses and depends upon. When you call `socket.set()` this is stored in an internal data structure that won't clash with internal properties.

https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/blob/master/lib/socket.js#L246

```
Socket.prototype.set = function (key, value, fn) {
  this.store.set(key, value, fn);
  return this;
};
```

Comment: +1 for including the function definition! So it's solely a matter of avoiding namespace collisions? Any other benefits to using the their datastore?

Comment: Not as far as I know, I guess collisions are the main thing.

Comment: Also to extend this answer, the reason for the get/set/del methods is to pass the key/value to the adaptor, by default this is a `MemoryStore`, but you can easily change the adaptor to mysql, redis, mongo etc etc

Answer (score 2):

I believe the primary reason is so the data attached to the socket is multi-process safe.

If you're app is single process, always will be single process, and you're sure you're not overriding an internal attribute, `socket.foo = bar` will be fine. It would still be best to use get/set as a matter of future-proofing and best-practices.

In a multi-process world, if you set `socket.foo = bar` in one process, then in another process `socket.foo` will be undefined.