# node.js socket.io socket.set() undefined property

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io, undefined

I have something like this.
This is my Controller.

```
    new singleton('User', function(model){
    model.find({username:data.username, password:_pass}, function(err,user){
        if (user.length==1)
        {
            socket.set('taxiId',user[0].id);
            cb(true);
        }
        else
            cb(false);
    });
});
```

If I set socket property like socket.set('name',value, function(){cb});

I get undefined here

```
        auth.authentificate(data, socket, function(logged){
        if (logged)
        {
            logs.login(data,socket);
            console.log(socket.taxiId);
            socket.emit('authOk',{err:'Ziaden error'});
        }
```

I tried set it with this

```
socket.set('taxiId', user[0].id, function(){cb(true);});
```

But nothing happend

Otherwise if I set property as

```
socket.taxiId = user[0].id;
```

It works simply good.

But here is one problem in asynchrone coding. 
If one setter `socket.taxiId = 1;` is called second getter `socket.taxiId;` returning undefined.

Comment: `socket.get` and `socket.set` are used for configuring socket, not for session management nor authorization. Would you please clarify your scenario first? Guess you want to manage sessions from different clients, if this is the case, read [Authorization and handshaking](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Authorizing).

Comment: Hello I read one thread [difference between set() and socket property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251407/socket-io-difference-between-socket-set-and-socket-property) If you click on this link, you will see what I want to do. And check last comment. "In a multi-process world, if you set socket.foo = bar in one process, then in another process socket.foo will be undefined." @shawnzhu